# Integer polynomial olympiad practice question

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

**Question**

I have this problem from Math Olympiad practice.

> Let $p$ be a polynomial with real coefficients and degree $n$. Suppose that $\frac{p(b)−p(a)}
> {b−a}$ is an integer for all $0 ≤ a < b ≤ n$. Prove that $\frac{p(b)−p(a)}{b−a}$ is an integer for all pairs of distinct integers $a < b$.

Below is a theorem for Divisibility.
If a and b are integers, and p(x) is a polynomial with integer coefficients, then p(a) − p(b) is always divisible by a − b.

**Attempt**

My initial thinking is to show that p(x) is a polynomial with integer coefficients, then apply the theorem for Disivibility above to prove that $\frac{p(b)−p(a)}{b−a}$ is an integer.

I have not figured out how to do it yet and would welcome suggestions.

Comment: $p$ does not need to have integer coefficients. Consider you can add or subtract any real number to the constant term.

Comment: It might be useful to note that $b-a$ divides $b^k-a^k$ for all integer $k \ge 0$.

Comment: Hint: Use the method of differences.

Answer (score 2):

Lets define  $P_k(x) = \frac{x(x-1)... (x-k+1)}{k!}$ with $P_0(x)=1$.

Note that $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $P_k(n)\in \mathbb{Z}$.

If $P\in \mathbb{R}[x]$, $\deg P=n$, verif $P(\{ m,m+1,...,m+n\} ) \subset \mathbb{Z}$, with $m\in \mathbb{Z}$, then there exist integers $a_k$ such that $P=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kP_k$ and so $P(\mathbb{Z}) \subset \mathbb{Z}$.

You can show it by induction, using $P(x+1)-P(x)$, for this problem we only need the second part which is very easy to demonstrate separately by the same way.

The first part is an interesting result that can be useful, a characterisation of polynomials with integer values.

So, we deduce that $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\frac{p(x)-p(0)}{x} \in \mathbb{Z}$.

$t(x)=p(x+1)-p(x)$, $\deg t=n-1$

$\frac{t(b)-t(a)}{b-a}=\frac{p(b+1)-p(a+1)}{b-a}-\frac{p(b)-p(a)}{b-a}$

Proceding by induction, because we have $\frac{t(b)-t(a)}{b-a}$ integer for $0\le a\lt b\le{n-1}$,
that is an integer for all $a\lt b$.

Then using:

$\frac{t(b)-t(a)}{b-a}+\frac{p(b)-p(a)}{b-a}=\frac{p(b+1)-p(a+1)}{b-a}$

$\frac{p(b+1)-p(a+1)}{b-a}-\frac{t(b)-t(a)}{b-a}=\frac{p(b)-p(a)}{b-a}$

And that $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\frac{p(x)-p(0)}{x} \in \mathbb{Z}$, we can be sure that $\frac{p(b)-p(a)}{b-a}$ always is an integer (taking $b=n$ in the first one, $a=-1$ in the second etc..).

Comment: Some MathJax tips: `\mathbb{Z}` is $\mathbb{Z}$, `\mathbb{R}` is $\mathbb{R}$, `\deg P` is $\deg P$.

Comment: Thank you, do you know how to do the integer intervals [n,m] with the double bar please?

Comment: Not sure I'm familiar with that notation.

Comment: Okay it is maybe a notation more used in France.